# MySQL: NATURAL JOIN Twice

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table that I would like to join itself twice. Let me explain:

The table `Mitarbeiter` contains the following attributes: `id, name, vorname, chefid`. Now I have to create a SELECT statement where I display the boss of a worker and the boss of those bosses.
I know it sounds confusing but you know how exercises in school are...

I got so far with this statement but it doesn't seem to work right:

```
select * from Mitarbeiter m inner join Mitarbeiter c on m.chefId = c.id 
inner join Mitarbeiter cc on p.chefId = cc.id;
```

And a little note: the exercise is German. `Mitarbeiter` means `employee` and Chef is the German term for "Boss".

And for those who are able to speak / understand German, here is the question I got:

```
Die Mitarbeiter einer Firma sind in drei Hierarchiestufen organisiert, 
d.h. ein Mitarbeiter kann einen Chef haben und dieser wiederum einen Chef. 
Dies ist über die Tabelle Mitarbeiter abgebildet, wobei ChefId auf den Id 
des Chefs zeigt.
=> Wie müsste ein „Selfjoin“ aussehen, der die Mitarbeiter Namen, 
   die ChefNamen und die ChefChefNamen ausgibt?
```

I'm sorry for my bad English but StackOverflow seem's like the only resource for me to ask my question.

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work right*. What is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have one actual error in your statement, you alias your second join table as `c` but then refer to it as `p` in the `ON` clause of your third join. It should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Mitarbeiter m 
            INNER JOIN Mitarbeiter c ON m.chefId = c.id 
            INNER JOIN Mitarbeiter cc ON c.chefId = cc.id;
```

Also you're using inner joins, this will eliminate people who don't have 2 levels of Chefs above them (the CEO, for example!) So you probably want LEFT JOINs instead.

Comment: +1. LEFT JOINs are what you need. (@Kyle - ... and eliminating CEO's is a bad thing? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name a, c.name, cc.name FROM MitArbeiter a, MittArbeiter c, MittArbeiter cc
WHERE a.chefid = c.id AND c.chefid = cc.id
```

Comment: No! Don't teach them ANSI Joins! What kind of monster are you?!

Comment: less typing :p im lazy